# Scroll to an selected item in scrollable mat-table angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

So I have an angular mat-table with a max-height, so you can scroll in it.
There is also a radar with dots that you can click. It doesn't matter what the radar is doing, only the dots are important.

You can either click on an item in the mat-table and the specific dot gets red, or you can click on a dot and the item in the mat-table gets a background-color.
If a dot gets clicked and the corresponding item in mat-table isn't visible, it should scroll to that specific item in the mat-table.

[Mat-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VXdK.png)

Code of mat-table:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="!isLoading">
              <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <mat-cell 
                  *matCellDef="let law" (click)="onSelect(law)"
                  [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == law.id}"
                  ><b>{{law.name}}</b>
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>
              <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Also, the item which is selected gets the class highlight.

I'm getting the element with:

`let element = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.highlight');`

So I tried to scroll to it with:
`element.scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});`
and
`element.prototype.scrollIntoView();` 
but neither of this is working.

Any ideas on how I can scroll to the specific item in the mat-table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what's wrong with your code without you providing a stackblitz example of your issue.

Anyway, scrolling to a specific row should be easy.

In your template define an id on the row element. You can also style the whole row to highlight the selected row:

```
<tr mat-row 
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [id]="row.position"
    [ngClass]="{'selected-row': row.position === selectedRowId}">
</tr>
```

In your typescript file, query the `@ViewChildren` of type `MatRow`:

```
@ViewChildren(MatRow, {read: ElementRef}) rows!: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLTableRowElement>>;
```

This will find all elements with the `MatRow` directive and read their `ElementRef`, which allows you accessing the `nativeElement`.

Then you can scroll into specific row by looking up proper element based on it's id and calling `scrollIntoView()` on it:

```
private scrollToIndex(id: number): void {
    this.selectedRowId = id;
    let elem = this.rows.find(row => row.nativeElement.id === id.toString());

    elem?.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'center', behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Here's a [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zoqvwe). I've wrapped the table in a div with `overflow-y: auto` and `max-width`, but it's not necessary for it to work - it was only to force the scrollbar visibility on higher resolution displays.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the working stackblitz. As you can see this is my first question here thats why I didnt include a stackblitz, going to do it next time.
My problem is solved. Have a good day!